# Add a custom terminal command to context menu in mac

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, services

Is there a way to add a custom command when I right click a folder in mac? I have a global NPM module which I run like this from the terminal:

> ~ make-assets

The behaviour I want to achieve is that when I right click a folder ("Source_Sans_Pro" in this example) I would have a "Make assets" option that would run the "make-assets" command in the terminal in the **correct folder**.

Preferably, I would like to have it below 'Get Info' but in the services submenu is also OK.

[image: mac context]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add it to the Services menu by creating an Automator Workflow.

Here are the steps:

1. Launch Automator.
2. Choose "Service" for the type of document.
3. Set the following two dropdowns to:`Service receives selected "Folder" in "Finder"`
4. Drag the "Run Shell Script" action to the Workflow pane.
5. Add your code and modify as appropriate.

Google is your friend if you're not familiar with Automator.